# creating a Class to calculate monthly payment

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, finance, calculation

I am trying to create a Class called Mortgage that has instance variables called principal, interest rate and term and a method call cal_monthly_payment.

I am not receiving an output when using the function. Could anyone help tell me what I am missing? Thanks for the help!

This is the formula I am using:
[image]

My current code is (UPDATED):

```
class Mortgage():

    def __init__(self,irate,numOfYear,amount):
        self.interestRate=irate
        self.years=numOfYear
        self.amount=amount

    def getInterestRate(self):
        return self.interestRate

    def getYears(self):
        return self.years

    def getAmount(self):
        return self.amount


    def setAmount(self,amount):
        self.amount=amount

    def setYears(self,years):
        self.years=years

    def setInterestRate(self,rate):
        self.interestRate=rate

    def getMonthlyPayment(self):
        monthlyInterestRate=self.interestRate/1200
        monthlyPayment=self.amount*monthlyInterestRate/(1-(1/(1+monthlyInterestRate)**(self.years*12)))
        return monthlyPayment

    def getTotalPayment():
        return self.getMonthlyPayment()*self.years*12
```

Input:

```
m=Mortgage(5.25,30,350000)
m
```

Output :

```
<__main__.Mortgage at 0x10553e70>
```

Comment: can you share the lines on which you created an instance of the class and used its methods?

Comment: You need to create a class instance and call it ... show that please. Also: Fix your IndentationErrors by [edit]ing

Comment: Why does `getMonthlyPayment()` expect an argument of `cal_monthly_payment`? If the point of `getMonthlyPayment()` is just to return the monthly payment, then it shouldn't need an argument.

Comment: I have updated the code I used in the question, I am not sure how to get the ending value

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this and thought I would share part of what I use. Maybe it will be of use to someone asking a similar question.
*edit*: Fixed minor bug with `period_index`: removed `+ 1`.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_financial as npf

class Mortgage():

    def __init__(self, principal: float, apr: float, term: int):
        self.principal: float = principal
        self.apr: float = apr
        self.term: int | float = term  # expecting years

    @property
    def terms(self):
        return self.term * 12

    @property
    def period_index(self) -> np.ndarray: 
        return np.arange(self.terms)

    @property
    def pmt(self):
        return npf.pmt(self.apr/12, self.terms, self.principal)

    @property
    def ppmt(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return npf.ppmt(self.apr/12, self.period_index, self.terms, self.principal)

    @property
    def ipmt(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return npf.ipmt(self.apr/12, self.period_index, self.terms, self.principal)

    @property
    def total_payment(self):
        return round(self.pmt * self.terms, 2)
        
    @property
    def total_interest(self):
        return np.sum(npf.ipmt(self.apr/12, self.period_index, self.terms, self.principal)).round(2)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Convert to formal string, for repr()."""
        return (
            f"{self.__class__.__module__}.{self.__class__.__qualname__}"
            f"(principal={self.principal}, apr={self.apr}, term={self.term})"
        )

    def __str__(self):
        """Convert to string, for str()."""
        newline = '\n'
        return (
            f"Mortgage for $ {self.principal:,.2f} with {self.apr:.2%} APR for {self.term} years. {newline}"
            f"The monthly payment will be $ {-self.pmt:,.2f}. {newline}"
            f"Total of {self.terms} payments will be $ {-self.total_payment:,.2f}, with a total interest paid of $ {-self.total_interest:,.2f}."
        )

m = Mortgage(principal=250_000, apr=4.25/100, term=15)
print(repr(m))
print(str(m))
```

Output:

```
__main__.Mortgage(principal=250000, apr=0.0425, term=15)
Mortgage for $ 250,000.00 with 4.25% APR for 15 years. 
The monthly payment will be $ 1,880.70. 
Total of 180 payments will be $ 338,525.28, with a total interest paid of $ 89,407.58.
```